# Correct use of CurrentProject.Connection for ADODB.Connection?

Tags: ms-access, vba

In Access VBA, I needed to use parameters for database inserts/updates so I started using a ADODB command.

The database to insert is always the current one, so I use CurrentProject.Connection.

Everything works without using conn.Open if I try to open it it will return error 3705:Operation is not allowed when the object is open.

Am I missing something important that will hit a connections limit? Can someone suggest a better way?

```
Dim sql As String
sql = "INSERT INTO "
sql = sql + "[table]"
sql = sql + "(field1,field2)"
sql = sql + "VALUES (@field1,@field2)"

Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Set conn = CurrentProject.Connection
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command

With cmd
.ActiveConnection = conn
.CommandType = adCmdText
.CommandText = sql
.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@field1", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, x)
.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@field2", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, y)
.Execute
End With
```

Comment: You can just use the conection without opening it--it's already open. What are you trying to do? Does your code work without explicitly opening the connection?

Comment: *Everything works without using conn.Open* ... but you do not use `conn.Open` here. Does posted code here err out?

Comment: Sorry I was not clear. Everything works perfectly when testing. I just do not know if in production there is the risk of maxing out connections? or the risk of error from multiple users using the same connection?

Answer (score 1):

Are you open to using DAO? you can use this:

```
Dim q        As DAO.QueryDef
Dim strSQL   As String

strSQL = "INSERT INTO table1 " & _
         "(City, Province) " & _
         "Values([pCity], [pProvince])"

Set q = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", strSQL)
q.Parameters("pCity") = "Edmonton"
q.Parameters("pProvince") = "Alberta"
q.Execute
```